# How to use reorder image in touch devices

Tags: media

I am using the Core default image system.
Right now i can use mouse to reorder images by drag/moving them up and down

But in touch mode with Smartphone/devices. it doesn't work.

Is there a plug in out there or any script i need to implement to make it work?

Thank you very much in advance.

Cheers
Kim[image]